# Generate Ansible fact once (per host)

Tags: ansible

I would like to generate a password and some other values when they do not exist yet.

Something like this:

```
- name: Retrieve or generate my_password
  generated_fact:
    shell: some shell command
    name: my_password
```

I have a working approach but am really unhappy with it since it is very verbose and error prone:

```
- name: Generate my_password
  shell: some shell command
  register: generate_password_task
  when: ansible_local.convoluted.bs.my_password is not defined

- name: Store my_password as local fact
  ini_file:
    path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact"
    section: bs
    option: my_password
    value: "{{ generate_password_task.stdout }}"
  when: generate_password_task.changed

- name: Reload Ansible local facts
  setup: filter=ansible_local
  when: generate_password_task.changed
```

Is there a high level abstraction for this task along the lines of the first code snippet? Or some other approach more sane than what I currently have?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/password.html should be a start, then for the "and some other values" this is not really clear to me. Why are you using facts here? Do you have multiple nodes? Do you know how to register and fetch data from `set_fact`? Have you red about `delegate_to`? Sorry for the questions, but the bottom of your issue is unclear, that's why I am asking.

Comment: I know about the password lookup plugin. Frustratingly for my use case, it stores the information on the control host with no option to store it on the target host. I know how to register data (my example here does) and how to use `set_fact`.

Comment: I'm not sure how `delegate_to` is relevant. My question is not about executing something only once when running against multiple hosts. It is about executing once on a single host, and not doing so again next time you run the same playbook.

Comment: `delegate_to` can work in the two ways and fix your frustration with the password task. You could generate the password from you localhost then delegate the creation of the ini file to the hosts needing one.

Comment: What would that look like? A playbook I run against localhost, that generates values locally, and then writes them to the hosts? I don't want these values to be stored on localhost, which leaves me with the original problem of how to generate them only once. Sure a few tasks will take care off that, but I am looking for a solution more simple than what I have currently.

Comment: Mhm, I would `stat` the file and act if it does not exists on the node? Or if the ini might exist with an empty or no password, use the `ini` lookup https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html?

Comment: Then you end up with the same amount of tasks, but more tasks that always need to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is the right one. There are few imperfections I see. One of them is 'dependence chain', when different tasks are depend on different conditions. It's hard to debug.

So, improvement one is to make a single condition:

```
- block: 
  when: ansible_local.convoluted.bs.my_password is not defined
  - name: Generate my_password
    shell: some shell command
    register: generate_password_task

  - name: Store my_password as local fact
    ini_file:
      path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact"
      section: bs
      option: my_password
      value: "{{ generate_password_task.stdout }}"

  - name: Reload Ansible local facts
    setup: filter=ansible_local
```

The second trick is to use `meta: end_host`, it allows to terminate play for the specific host without errors and additional skips.

```
- hosts: ...
  tasks:
   - meta: end_play
     when: ansible_local.convoluted.bs.my_password is defined

   - name: Generate my_password
     shell: some shell command
     register: generate_password_task

   - name: Store my_password as local fact
     ini_file:
       path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact"
       section: bs
       option: my_password
       value: "{{ generate_password_task.stdout }}"

   - name: Reload Ansible local facts
     setup: filter=ansible_local
```

But you need to keep it as a separate play to use it with 'end_host'.

Comment: I will adopt this block approach, as it indeed makes the dependency chain less hairy and more explicit. Still a far cry from a nice high level task. The `end_host` bit is not relevant I think. I've amended my question to make it more clear it is about running something once *per host*, across multiple runs.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be my approach, in two tasks.

Note that this has been checked when:

1. The `ini` file does not exists
2. The `ini` file is present but there is no `bs` section
3. The `ini` file is present, have a `bs` section, but the section does not include a `my_password` option
4. The `ini` file is present, have a `bs` section, but the option `my_password` is empty
5. The `ini` file is present, have a `bs` section and have a value for the option `my_password`

The cases 1 to 4 does end in a change of the ini file with a newly generated password, when the last case ends in a skipped task.

And here are the two tasks doing this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    actual_password: "{{ lookup('ini', 'my_password section=bs file=/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact', errors='ignore') }}"

- ini_file:
    path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact
    section: bs
    option: my_password
    value: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits,hexdigits,punctuation') }}"
  when: actual_password|length == 0
```

Those are using

- the [`ini`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html) lookup in order to confirm that the ini and value are not yet set
- the [`password`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/password.html) plugin to generate a password

The condition (`when: actual_password|length == 0`) to write the `ini` is based on experimentation

- Thanks to the [`errors='ignore'`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins) syntax in the `ini` lookup, the variable `actual_password` ends up being an empty string if the file or section does not exists, because both those cases are causing the lookup to return an error
- If the section exists but does not contains the option then the lookup ends up returning an empty array `[]`
- If the option is there but empty, the lookup return that empty string

Knowing all that is making the test relevant: `[]|length == 0` and `''|length == 0` are both true.

A last note on the `password` plugin, yes it does write a file on your controller host, but you are not forced to consider it, use it, or even, well, store it.
The plugin return the password, so you can easily use it as you would for any other variable in the `value` attribute of your `ini_file` module.
And then, if you don't want to store it on the controller host, do as you would do for anything you don't care about in linux, redirect it to `/dev/null`, either way, the password is in your `ini` file now.

And if you need to re-use that same password later in the playbook, just store it via an extra `set_fact`

```yaml
- set_fact:
    actual_password: "{{ lookup('ini', 'my_password section=bs file=/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact', errors='ignore') }}"

- block:
  - set_fact:
      new_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits,hexdigits,punctuation') }}"

  - ini_file:
      path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact
      section: bs
      option: my_password
      value: "{{ new_password }}" 
  when: actual_password|length == 0
```

Given this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        actual_password: "{{ lookup('ini', 'my_password section=bs file=/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact', errors='ignore') }}"

    - ini_file:
        path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact
        section: bs
        option: my_password
        value: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits,hexdigits,punctuation') }}"
      when: actual_password|length == 0
```

Here is a double run of it:

```
/ansible # cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact 
cat: can't open '/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact': No such file or directory
/ansible # ansible-playbook play.yml 

PLAY [local] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
ok: [local]

TASK [ini_file] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [local]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0  

/ansible # cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/convoluted.fact 
[bs]
my_password = fnI;L3FpR5207,8,jxGP 
/ansible # ansible-playbook play.yml 

PLAY [local] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [local]

TASK [ini_file] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [local]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```